# C# Card Printer Has Margins

Tags: c#, printing

i have a printer for printing Cards, but there is a problem in my exiting print.
what i did?
i read a template image and then using DrawString to draw texts in my image.
then i save it and when i print in windows it works fine but when i print it with c# code ,
it has some margin from left and top.
code for drawing

```
bmp.SetResolution(390, 250);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            //g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;

            RectangleF rectfAppleId = new RectangleF(0, 0, 500, 100);
            g.DrawString(cardInfo.AppleId, new Font(fontName, GetLocations("applieid", 5), FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, rectfAppleId);
```

and this codes for printing :

```
 private void Print(Bitmap img)

        {
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument myPrintDocument1 = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
            PrintDialog myPrinDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
            myPrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            myPrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            myPrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("cardSize", 336, 211);
            myPrintDocument1.OriginAtMargins = true;

            currentPrintBitMap = img;
            myPrintDocument1.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(myPrintDocument2_PrintPage);
            ComboboxItem selected = (ComboboxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
            myPrinDialog1.Document = myPrintDocument1;
            myPrinDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = selected.Value.ToString();
            myPrintDocument1.Print();
        }
        private void myPrintDocument2_PrintPage(System.Object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentPrintBitMap != null)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;
                e.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                e.PageSettings.Landscape = true;

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(currentPrintBitMap, 0, 0);
                e.PageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                currentPrintBitMap.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

for testing i changed text location to 0 and 0
and i saw the problem , it has a margin even when i set margins to (0,0,0,0).
[image]

and in my preview every thing is ok :

[image]

is there a way to fix it?
my printer is fargo dtc1250e.

Comment: The bmp has a margin.  Open BMP with a text editor.  Then check the parameters using Wiki as a reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: thanks , u mean i dont send bmp format for printing?

Comment: The BMP has a margin that is being added to the location.